# Select data from different table and insert calculations into new table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am new to SQL and I have a problem that I'm not able to solve. I have four tables and each of them have two columns. I have to take the first column of the first three tables and calculate the sum of columns. The end result must be added to the first column of the fourth table. Then I have to take the second column of first three tables and multiply the sum of columns. Then end result must be added to the second column of the fourth table.

I need all possible combinations. So if first three tables contain 10 rows then fourth table must contain 10*10*10 = 1000 rows. Is this possible to do using with SQL?

Table1:

```
COL1   COL2
   2      6
   4      8
```

Table2:

```
COL1   COL2
  12     16
  14     18
```

Table3:

```
COL1   COL2
  22     26
  24     28
```

In this case Table4 should contain rows:

```
COL1   COL2
  36   2496  (COL1: T1.C1+T2.C1+T3.C1; COL2: T1.C2*T2.C2*T3.C3)
  38   3328
  38   2808
  40   3744
  38   2688
  40   3584
  40   3024
  42   4032
```

Comment: Please add some sample data to your question.  Your current question is not answerable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cross join the 3 tables and do the calculations:

```
insert into Table4(COL1, COL2)
select
  t1.col1 + t2.col1 + t3.col1 COL1,
  t1.col2 * t2.col2 * t3.col2 COL2
from Table1 t1
cross join Table2 t2
cross join Table3 t3;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/j6BuAyathK9qJWz56GeTtm/1).
In case `Table4` does not exist you can create it like this:

```
create table Table4 as
select
  t1.col1 + t2.col1 + t3.col1 COL1,
  t1.col2 * t2.col2 * t3.col2 COL2
from Table1 t1
cross join Table2 t2
cross join Table3 t3;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/j6BuAyathK9qJWz56GeTtm/2).

Results:

```
| COL1 | COL2 |
| ---- | ---- |
| 36   | 2496 |
| 38   | 2688 |
| 38   | 2808 |
| 40   | 3024 |
| 38   | 3328 |
| 40   | 3584 |
| 40   | 3744 |
| 42   | 4032 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on strictly what you've stated in your question, below query (in MySQL) would solve your problem.

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE4 AS 
SELECT 
    SUM(C1) AS C1, SUM(C2) AS C2 
FROM
(
SELECT T1.C1 AS C1, T1.C2 AS C2 FROM TABLE1 T1
UNION ALL
SELECT T2.C1, T2.C2 FROM TABLE2 T2
UNION ALL
SELECT T3.C1, T3.C2 FROM TABLE3 T3
) x
```

Syntax would be more or less same in other RDBMS solutions also.